# MediaPlayer sound gets interrupted by animation

Tags: android, animation, audio, media-player

I want to play a sound while animating a view.

I'm playing the sound with MediaPlayer, and the sound gets interrupted when I play the animation (when I say interrupted, I mean stops as soon as the animation starts).

This happens for both property animations (done using nineoldandroids lib) and also for sequence animation (frame by frame).

The sound code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context , rawSoundFileId);

            if (mp == null) {
                return;
            }

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });

            if (mp != null) {
                mp.start();
            }
```

I also tried moving the sound to a separate thread, and this still happens.

any ideas for resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, is is recommended to use SoundPool to play short sounds.
If I load the sounds to the pool in advance, the animation does not interrupt the sound anymore.